# Select all checkboxes in a React functional component failing, I suspect due to render happening too fast

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

Edit:
The solution, as sschwei1 pointed out in the comments, is to do the following in the funciton where I add selected values:

```
 const addToSelected = (user: any) => {
    let tempSelectedUser: any[] = selectedUsers;
    if (tempSelectedUser.indexOf(user) === -1)
      setSelectedUsers([...tempSelectedUser, user]);
  };
```

I've written a component that contains a range of checkboxes with the option to select all. Each checkbox is related to a JSON data object that I have stored in an array in the state named "data".

I am using the Ant Design package for my components BTW: https://ant.design/components/checkbox/

I've written what to me looks like a fairly elegant solution to select and deselect individual or all items. This approach will ensure that whatever is in my selectedUsers variable in the state will determine whether each checkbox will display if it is checked or not, including the "select all" one.

My code seems to work well, but my checkboxes are not displaying as checked when they are in the list of selected items. When I output the values to the console, however, the script that determines whether an element should be selected seems to return true without displaying that the element is selected. (note the console.log in my code which returns false the first time, then always true)

I suspect there is a delay between when the item is added to the list of selected elements and when the component renders, causing the script to return false at render time. I've considered reloading the component a few milliseconds later, but that seems like a hackey solution.

Here are some snippets that show what I am trying:

```
...
  const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState<any[]>([]);
...
  const addToSelected = (user: any) => {
    let tempSelectedUser: any[] = selectedUsers;
    tempSelectedUser.indexOf(user) === -1 && tempSelectedUser.push(user);
    setSelectedUsers(tempSelectedUser);
  };

  const removeFromSelected = (user: any) => {
    let setValue = selectedUsers;
    let tempSelectedUser = setValue.filter((el: any) => {
      return el.id !== user.id;
    });
    setSelectedUsers(tempSelectedUser);
  };

  const userSelected = (userToFind: any) => {
    let found = false;
    selectedUsers.map((user: any) => {
      if (userToFind.id === user.id) found = true;
    });
    return found;
  };
...
  <Checkbox
    className={"Select All"}
    onChange={(e) => {
      e.target.checked
      ? setSelectedUsers(data)
      : setSelectedUsers([]);
    }
    checked={selectedUsers === data}
  />
...
{users.map((user: any) => (
...
  <Checkbox
    checked={userSelected(user)}
    onChange={(e) => {
      e.target.checked
        ? addToSelected(user)
        : removeFromSelected(user);
    }}
  />
...
)}
...
```

Here is a quick screenshot of the interface as well as my console
[image]

Edit: I just double-checked and the select all function is working at least. I can also see when I select and deselect items that after I do something else that causes the component to refresh, that the values that I expect to see displays as checked. I'm going to implement a refresh for the time being, but I'm really hoping for a more elegant solution.

Edit: So the forced refresh is also not giving me the expected result. I've also noticed that the deselect works perfectly, but I can't seem to select a checkbox besides through the select all option.

Edit: I've changed the check to see if the user is in the selectedUsers state variable to a function that rather compares the user's ID's bases on @classydraught's suggestion (thanks BTW). It does not affect the functionaity unfortunatly.

Here is also an example of the data that can be found in the "data" object (note this this is largely dummy data for now):

```
[
  {
    createdAt: null
    description: null
    email: "sysadmin@ilabqa.com"
    id: 1
    imageLink: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/1/image"
    lastActivity: null
    name: "System Admin"
    role: null
    status: "ACTIVE"
    username: "sysadmin"
},
{
    createdAt: null
    description: null
    email: "testadmin@ilabqa.com"
    id: 2
    imageLink: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/2/image"
    lastActivity: null
    name: "Test Admin"
    role: null
    status: "DEACTIVE"
 }
]
```

Comment: You are using `users.map(...)`, where is the `users` object coming from?

Comment: @sschwei1 I am reading that from our back-end. It returns an array of users each in JSONformat:  
await getAllUsersWithoutPagination().then((response) => {
        setData(response.data.data);
        setFilteredData(response.data.data);
});

Comment: @phunder depending a lot on object references is not a good idea. As when react rerenders object address changes. Instead, a better idea would be using `id` or some `key` that uniquely identifies user object.

Comment: @classydraught I've implemented what I understood you mentioned, but as noted it does not have any effect. Did I grasp your meaning correctly?

Comment: @phunder I think your problem is how you update your state, you create a tempArr and push a value to it, react probably sees that the reference of it's vale hasn't changed and don't trigger rerender, try to update your state like this `setSelectedUsers([...tempSelectedUser, user]);`, the spread operator will add all current user to a new array and also add the new user, this would also explain why your deselect is working, `.filter` is creating a new instance of an array, so the reference to the previous `selectedUsers` has changed and it updates accordingly

Comment: Thanks, @sschwei1! THat solved it! I'm grateful for your kind assistance :)

Comment: @phunder glad I could help, I'll leave it as an answer as soon as I have a pc to use ;)